# Advertising multiple services from a single node

Tags: ros, service, ros-service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm writing a node, that advertises multiple services.

Should I use a diffrent object name for each service, or the same name (see below)?
As I understand it, this results in either multiple instances of a ros::ServiceServer Object, or a single one in the latter case..

Ex. 1:

> ros::ServiceServer service1 = nodeHandle.advertiseService("serviceOne", serviceOneFunction);
> ros::ServiceServer service2 = nodeHandle.advertiseService("serviceTwo", serviceTwoFunction);

Ex. 2:

> ros::ServiceServer service = nodeHandle.advertiseService("serviceOne", serviceOneFunction);
> ros::ServiceServer service = nodeHandle.advertiseService("serviceTwo", serviceTwoFunction);

Which Option should I choose? Is there anything else to remember, while writing nodes, that advertise multiple services?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211986/advertising-multiple-services-from-a-single-node/) by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first one. The second one doesn't even compile.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-24**:
Thanks, this solves my problem completely

**Comment by [Reiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/22377/reiner/) on 2015-06-24**:
Do you have any experience regarding performance, when a node advertises many services?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-06-24**:
It's not a function call obviously, but especially if you use a persistent connection in the client it's OK for speed.